# similarity calculus between lists of tuples with different length

Tags: python, similarity

I need to generate a dataframe or matrix with  distance between  lists of tuples which are of different lengths (any distance showing similarity other than matrix similarity) with Python.

```
x=[(15,7),(12,7),(80,3),(10,8)]   y=[(12,4),(11,9)]    z=[(1,1),(16,7),(0,3),(10,5),(3,44)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Each list can be seem as a set of 2D points. Calculate the center of mass of each set. Calculate the euclidian distance between every pair of center of mass and put it in a square matrix.

```
import math

def center_of_mass(points):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    
    for point in points:
        x += point[0]
        y += point[1]
    
    x /= len(points)
    y /= len(points)
    
    return x, y

def euclidian_distance(point1, point2):
    return math.sqrt((point1[0] - point2[0])*(point1[0] - point2[0]) + (point1[1] - point2[1])*(point1[1] - point2[1]))
    
def get_distance_matrix(data):
    centers_of_mass = [center_of_mass(points) for points in data]
    distance_matrix = [[0.0 for i in range(len(centers_of_mass))] for j in range(len(centers_of_mass))]
    
    for i in range(len(centers_of_mass)):
        for j in range(len(centers_of_mass)):
            distance_matrix[i][j] = euclidian_distance(centers_of_mass[i], centers_of_mass[j])
    
    return distance_matrix
```